# My Code is not working on Live Server

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
if(isset($_SESSION['jobSess']))
{
    $jobSlug=$_SESSION['jobSess'];
    header('Location:http://cablingjobs.com/jobs/view/'.$jobSlug.'/');
    exit;
}
```

I put above code in my staging site of wpengine.Its perfectly working.

But when when using same on live site it doesn't redirect.

i.e. `header()` is not working properly.
May be the issue is cache cause when i see source of site.

each link having some content.

for example:

```
src='http://3bceom1dyooq2orklp30o45s.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.js?ver=3.1-20121105'
```

what is this `3bceom1dyooq2orklp30o45s` in above link ?

Comment: improve your question

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your script is hosted on CDN (Content Delivery Network) .

And this part `3bceom1dyooq2orklp30o45s` is added by CDN in the url.